# Do I have to specify memory management properties with ARC?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Since, ARC is now a standard for many years do I have to write code like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (copy) NSString *subtitle;
```

Or just simplify it to this?

```
@property NSString *title;
@property NSString *subtitle;
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Do I have to specify memory management properties with ARC?

In short, if you want anything other than the default behavior, yes you do. The default behavior is `atomic` and `strong`. If you want copy behavior, for example, then you must specify `copy`. If you want non-atomic behavior, then you must specify `nonatomic`.

---

So, let us consider the two `title` renditions:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title; // nonatomic
@property NSString *title;                     // defaults to atomic, strong
```

The two are different insofar as the first is `nonatomic` and the latter is `atomic`. Also, the first explicitly uses `retain`, which in ARC achieves the same behavior as `strong`. That having been said, we prefer to use `strong` (instead of `retain`) in ARC because we now reason about the reference types, not reference counts.

If you really wanted to simplify that first example, you could remove `retain` and rely on the fact that object properties default to `strong`, by default.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *title;         // strong (by default), nonatomic
```

And you would only remove `nonatomic` if you really wanted to introduce the overhead of atomic accessor methods.

---

Consider these two:

```
@property (copy) NSString *subtitle;           // copy semantics
@property NSString *subtitle;                  // strong reference only
```

These two are different that the former employs copy semantics (providing critical protection against `NSMutableString` references changing behind its back) and the latter does not.

Answer (score 0):

ARC has default property params.
the following 2 property definitions are the same.
@property NSArray *name;
@property (strong, atomic, readwrite) NSArray *name;